# Android studio 2.2 preview 5 design editor/preview seem to be broken?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

After updating from Android studio 2.2 preview 4 to 5, Design and Preview tabs stopped to show previews.

They don't show anything, only the error (described below) and a tip "Try to refresh the layout".

Refreshing and choosing different options in a top bar (API, device orientation) doesn't help.

Was trying File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart. Doesn't help either.

Any suggestions?

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 8: @android:drawable/ic_menu_send
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.parseFileName(ResourceItem.java:585)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.parseXmlToResourceValue(ResourceItem.java:405)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceItem.getResourceValue(ResourceItem.java:240)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.AbstractResourceRepository.getConfiguredResources(AbstractResourceRepository.java:393)
at com.android.ide.common.res2.AbstractResourceRepository.getConfiguredResources(AbstractResourceRepository.java:349)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache$1.compute(ResourceResolverCache.java:166)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache$1.compute(ResourceResolverCache.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache.getResourceResolver(ResourceResolverCache.java:163)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.Configuration.getResourceResolver(Configuration.java:1212)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.getResourceResolver(RenderTask.java:198)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:425)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$52(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

**UPD1:** Seem to be an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215509&q=java.nio.file.InvalidPathException&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened#makechanges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Android studio 2.2 (Canary) Preview 6 (also see [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215509&q=java.nio.file.InvalidPathException&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened#makechanges)).

Answer (score 0):

In your activity.xml file there must be a line as `xmlns:app=""`. Delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in **xml** file check that no 
`android:`  or  `xmlns:app=""`